django: Unsupported lookup for ForeignKey annotated fields
In a django application, I have a Question model with a custom manager:
class QuestionManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return QuestionQS(self.model).get_queryset()


class Question(models.Model):
    objects = QuestionManager()
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=40)

and a Choice model which has a foreign key to Question:
class Choice(models.Model):
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name="choices", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

In my Queryset class I have a custom annotation (annotate_flages method to annotate status) that I expect it to be included in every queryset and another custom annotation (extra_annotations method that annotates is_editable) which I want to include manually:
class QuestionQS(models.QuerySet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.annotate_flags()

    def annotate_flags(self):
        qs = self.annotate(
            status=Case(
                When(label__icontains="active", then=Value(1)),
                When(label__icontains="closed", then=Value(0)),
                default=Value(0),
                output_field=IntegerField(),
            )
        )
        return qs

    def extra_annotations(self):
        one_hour_ago = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
        return self.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                "choices",
                queryset=Choice.objects.annotate(
                    is_editable=Case(
                        When(
                            Q(Q(created_at__gt=one_hour_ago) & Q(question__status=1)),
                            then=True,
                        ),
                        default=False,
                        output_field=BooleanField(),
                    )
                ),
            )
        )

My problem is that the default annotations (status) are included in the querysets but I do not have access to them from my custom extra_annotations method.
When calling the custom method like:
questions = Question.objects.get_queryset().extra_annotations()

I get unsupported lookup error:
Unsupported lookup 'status' for ForeignKey or join on the field not permitted.

